# Link to ID tag from a different page does not jump to section

Tags: html

I have reusable navbar with links to id/sections as follows:

```html
<!-- Item -->
<section id="item"></section>

<!-- Link -->
<a href="http://localhost:3000/#item">Item</a>
```

This works on the homepage as intended. However, when linking from another page (such as `http://localhost:3000/blog`) the link only takes me to the top of the landing page and not to the actual id. The window location still says it's `http://localhost:3000/#item` though.

Clicking again once on the landing page works.

Comment: if #item is inside blog then it should be http://localhost:3000/blog#item if not working means no #item element is exist,

Comment: The #item does not exist inside /blog and only on the landing page i.e. the only occurrence is localhost:3000/#blog

Comment: either try with localhost:3000/index.html#blog or whatever your index file is there.

Comment: @BBQuercus Please provide some kind of live example where it is possible to test the links you have and how the page does not scroll. Keep in mind that for scrolling you must have enough content to actually scroll. When you are already at the bottom of the page you can't scroll any further "down".

Comment: have you try this localhost:3000/index.html#item

Comment: Yes, I'm using Nuxt/Vue and "/" is the route to my homepage. While index.html exists it can't be accessed. I'm just making a codepen project as example.

Comment: I just made a project (https://codepen.io/bbquercus/project/editor/DyeRLP) which doesn't face the same issues...

Comment: @BBQuercus Then provide a webpage/project/[MCVE] which does show the issue. Jumping to an anchor is a basic functionality of a browser and is most likely not broken.